# В css font-face не работает

Tags: css

Здравствуйте! Проблема в том, что на сайте не меняется шрифт во всех браузерах,помогите, вот код:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'InformShadowCTT';
src: url('samodroid.ru/fonts/InformShadowCTT.otf'),                   url('samodroid.ru/fonts/InformShadowCTT.ttf'),
url('samodroid.ru/fonts/InformShadowCTT.woff'); 
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В каком браузере? или во всех браузерах?

Answer (score 4):

Кстати, может к url надо http:// дописать или хотя-бы // ?

А если  у вас на том-же домене, то вообще уберите имя домена из url и http тоже.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'InformShadowCTT';
    src: url('/fonts/InformShadowCTT.otf'),
         url('/fonts/InformShadowCTT.ttf'),
         url('/fonts/InformShadowCTT.woff'); 
}
```

Comment: @eicto, спасибо, заработало!